# Security problem with /openapi.json in docker running python fastapi protected by api-key

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

**Background**

I have created a [fastapi](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi) app and secured all endpoints, including the /docs and /openapi.json with the [API key approach](https://medium.com/data-rebels/fastapi-authentication-revisited-enabling-api-key-authentication-122dc5975680). 
Of course, everything is working on my local machine, with no errors.

**The problem**

I have then created a docker container (using this [image](https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker)) and on my machine, when I run the container, everything is also working fine.

Here is my environment:

1. Windows 10 Enterprise version 1803 OS build: 17134.1425
2. Python  3.8.2 64b
3. Docker desktop community version 2.3.0.2 (45183) with engine: 19.03.8 and compose 1.25.5

But then, when I download my repo into a new server that already has docker installed, and after building my image, when the container runs, if I try to access the /docs endpoint sending the API-Key I'm receiving an error: ***Forbidden /openapi.json***. 
Looking into chrome developer tools, I could see the message I send when an endpoint is reached with no API-key.

I confess that I'm confused right now because use docker was supposed to avoid this type of conundrum.

For now, I have removed the security check from docs and /openapi.json (which in hindsight maybe makes more sense) and everything is working but it would be nice to understand the reason for this error.

New server configuration

1. Ubuntu 16.04 xenial with kernel x86_64 Linux 4.4.0-45-generic
2. Python  3.8.2 64b
3. Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be and docker-compose 1.25.0, build 0a186604